# Node.js maintenance policy: Difference between LTS and maintenance releases?

Tags: node.js

The Node.js maintenance policy is described by the [Node.js Long-term Support Working Group](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS)

[image]

I suppose that maintanence release will get lesser updates. But what are the exact differences between LTS and maintenance?

Comment: I don't think there's much difference. both only get bugfixes and non-breaking changes. The important thing is that once it's in maintenance, you can be sure that there's a new active LTS version available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answered by a Node.js Foundation Member

> There are both Active + Maintenance LTS
>
> The first 18 months are active, the last 12 are maintenance.
>
> During active we try and backport as much as reasonably possible.
>   During Maintenance we only backport security fixes and major
>   unavoidable bug fixes

Source: https://github.com/nodejs/LTS/issues/76